Vertical align sidebar in Ant Design
Currently I have this but i want to customize the label of each menu to be vertical align with ant design in react JS  and here is my code right now
 <div style={{width:'256px',height:'100vh'}}>

        <img src={logo}  style={{width:'40px',height:'40px',padding:'40px'}}/>
        <Menu
                mode="inline"
                defaultSelectedKeys={['231']}
                openKeys={stateOpenKeys}
                onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
                
                items={items}
            />
       </div>


I want the Overview,Payroll, employee to be vertical align.
